# How to use the thread to show something on the label on the form?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a method

```
 public static string  MyWrite2()
    {
         string p = "hi";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            p += "kk";
        }

        return p;

    }
```

and i want to write a thread which when i click on btn1 it call MyWrite2 and put the result on label1, how can i do it?

Comment: Any operation that modifies the user interface must be done from the main thread. If you want to use threads at all (instead of Tasks or the TPL) then use them only to compute or process things. When you want to display the result of that computation take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: You do tealise that meoth will never return anything but "hikk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Invoke() method on a label1 and pass a method which does the writing as an argument to the Invoke() method.

Using anonymous method it would be sth like:

```
label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
  label1.Text = MyWrite2();
}
));
```

In the other thread.

Comment: i want to use thread! is there any way?

Comment: You can have above code in the other thread you are talking about. That's exactly the point of Invoke() method.